# Configurating .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

My htaccess file is giving my webpage a 500 error and i do not understand why ...
this is its code:

```
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gallery-page.php?galerie=$1
```

If i take the .htaccess file away, then I get 404 errors on the pages i needed renaming.

If i have the .htaccess file with no code in it, I still get an error 500.

Please if somebody can help me understand, it would be great !

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite?

Comment: yes i have enabled it

Comment: The absolute first thing you always do on a 500 error, is check the server’s error log. (The apache default 500 error document even tells you that you should look for more info there.)